# Body color and button bg in Email

Tags: html, css, email

I have been strugling with email html.

1) is that the pay now a button is not all green in Outlook. But look correct in gmail web

2) The width of the table/ td on 560px is not applied in Outlook

3) In gmail web mail the body color light green is domaninated by the table white color.

4) I tried to make margin on 10px on the HR by the comment. But in Outlook the margin (top) is much higher.

Please help before it get grey hairs :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <br></br>
    <body background="#cbebff" bgcolor="#cbebff" style="background:#cbebff; bgcolor:#cbebff; min-height:1000px; color:#000000;font-family:Arial, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px">
        <center>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" width="560px">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" width="560px" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#3590FF"><img src="http://www.domain.de/images/stories/help_filer/Toplogo.png"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" background="#FFFFFF"><strong>{hello} {fullname}.</strong></td>
                    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" background="#FFFFFF"><div align="right">{order_number_lbl} : {order_number}<br>{order_date_lbl} : {order_date}</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td colspan="2" width="560px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" background="#FFFFFF">{payment_missing}
                        <br></br><br></br>
                        <a style="width: 250px; padding: 15px; bgcolor:#62c462; background:#62c462; font-weight: bold;  color: #000000; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid #000000; font-size: 150%;text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.domain.de/index.php?option=com_epay&set_amount={order_total_mail}&set_invoice={order_id}&set_phone={billing_address_start}{phone}{billing_address_end}">{pay_now_lbl}</a>
                        <br></br><br></br>
                        <table width="100%" style="padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;border-radius: 3px;background: #fafafa;">
                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>{customer_note_lbl} :</strong><br><hr style="margin: 10px !important;">{customer_note}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br></br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <table width="560" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><div align="center"><font color="#000000"><strong>Print.dk - Berlin</strong></font></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><hr>
                    <div align="center"><font color="#000000"><strong>Email : <a href="ronni@print.dk">Info@printdk.de</a> - Web : <a href="www.printdk.de">www.printdk.de</a></strong><a href="www.printdk.de"></a></font></div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pics :
https://www.printdk.de/tmp/mail_gmail.jpg

https://www.printdk.de/tmp/mail_outlook.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

1 :

```html
<p style="width: 150px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; bgcolor:#62c462; background:#62c462; font-weight: bold;  color: #000000; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid #000000; font-size: 150%;text-decoration:none;"><a  href="your_link">Pay Now</a></p>
```

2 :

```html
<tr valign="top">
<td colspan="2" width="560px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" background="#FFFFFF">

<table width="560" style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
<tr>
<td>Payment Losing</td>
<tr><td>
 <br><br><br><br>
<p style="width: 150px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; bgcolor:#62c462; background:#62c462; font-weight: bold;  color: #000000; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid #000000; font-size: 150%;text-decoration:none;"><a  href="your_link">Pay Now</a></p>
</td></tr>
</tr>
 
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

3 : you have to give width to your outer table to get light green background and put all your email contents in it. this way you can do.

4 : instead of giving `margin` give `padding` to your `td`. as sometimes `margin` won't render by some email engine.

hope this helps.

you can refer here for [HTML Email Guidelines](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for advice :-)

Can i get you to remove my domain in the a link in your answer?
It where a mistake i did not change it to domain.de
I dont want this url crawled. Thanks.

Comment: updated my answer. is this the same that you want? link has been removed

Comment: Great. Sorry to be so difficult. But you only removed it in 1) its still there in 2)
You helped me a lot with :-)

Comment: @Ronni... now check.. did it solve? my pleasure. glad to help you. :)